# Fourier Transform An FM synthesized wave.

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Greetings StackExchange,
(I hope this question comes under Mathematics and not Physics)

I've been attempting a Fourier Transform on an FM synthesized wave (as below). After a long time (about 8 days) of trying the integration, I realized that FM synthesis results in a non-periodic wave and that I shouldn't integrate it from 0 to 1 as base periodicity (Correct me if I'm wrong). I need help with the integration (I'm quite sure that it is integrable because I tried visualizing the wave using Desmos).

The wave - $f\left(t\right)=A\left(\sin\left(2\pi nt\ +\ r\sin\left(2\pi mt\right)\right)\ \right)$ where n, m, A & r are constants.

The integral - $v\left(x\right)=\int \left(\sin\left(2\pi nt\ +\ r\sin\left(2\pi mt\right)\right)\ \right)\ \ e^{-2\pi ixt}\ dt$

Thank You

[Edit] The wave is periodic. I was wrong.

Comment: The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\sin\left(2\pi nt\ +\ r\sin\left(2\pi mt\right)\right)\ \right)\ \ e^{-2\pi ixt}\ dt$ does not exist. Do you really want to Fourier transform the wave f rather then expand it into a Fourier series? If so, you have to do it in the sense of distributions.

Comment: So will expanding it into a Fourier Series work?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get how it already is a Fourier series. Because it is a sin of sin and not just the sum of two wave equations. Am I missing out on something?

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. I didn't see you have a sin of a sin. I read it as a sum of two sin. That certainly complicates the complicates the computation of the Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Are $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$? If so, $f$ is periodic. But you wrote that it is non-periodic. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, n,m∈Z. It is periodic, I was wrong. (I'll edit the question)